# Cannot compile esp32cam after upgrade to espressif framework 6.0.1

Tags: c, esp32, platformio

I was having issues with serial monitor and ESP_LOGI, because no mater what I do I got no signal from the esp32cam, but the program managed to compile and run inside the esp32cam, then I got the brilliant idea of upgrading, think I had 5. something and now I got espressif32 @ 6.0.1  6.0.1, ***I simply went into platformio left menu -> dependencies -> update***, now every time I want to compile, everything works fine until it reach **esp32-camera/conversions/esp_jpeg_decode.c as well asking for spiram.h** and I get the follow warning on the code below

As you can see its trying to link what it seems a deprecated version (or correct one?), but I didn't touch or change anything, I just did a plain update, also did try doing a clean build by erasing everything from the .pio folder, either manually or using the platformio left side menu, got the same result every time

The program only takes a picture every 1 sec and I was playing with wifi in order to connect to my ssid, the takin picture part was fine the wifi part don't know, that's why I need the serial monitor, now it simply wont compile anything, help is welcome

***I'm using the esp32cam v2.0, platformio core 6.1.6 and espressif 6.0.1(was version 5, not exaclty which one)***

```
Compiling .pio\build\esp32cam\bootloader\soc\esp32\touch_sensor_periph.o
Compiling .pio\build\esp32cam\bootloader\soc\esp32\uart_periph.o
Generating partitions .pio\build\esp32cam\partitions.bin
Compiling .pio\build\esp32cam\lib533\esp32-camera\conversions\esp_jpg_decode.o
Compiling .pio\build\esp32cam\lib533\esp32-camera\conversions\jpge.o
cc1.exe: warning: command-line option '-fno-rtti' is valid for C++/D/ObjC++ but not for C
Archiving .pio\build\esp32cam\bootloader\esp-idf\soc\libsoc.a
Compiling .pio\build\esp32cam\lib533\esp32-camera\conversions\to_bmp.o
Indexing .pio\build\esp32cam\bootloader\esp-idf\soc\libsoc.a
.pio/libdeps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/conversions/esp_jpg_decode.c: In function 'esp_jpg_decode':
.pio/libdeps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/conversions/esp_jpg_decode.c:105:41: warning: passing argument 2 of 'jd_prepare' from 
incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  105 |     JRESULT jres = jd_prepare(&decoder, _jpg_read, work, 3100, &jpeg);
      |                                         ^~~~~~~~~
      |                                         |
      |                                         uint32_t (*)(JDEC *, uint8_t *, uint32_t) {aka long unsigned int (*)(JDEC *, unsigned char *, long unsigned int)}
In file included from .pio/libdeps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/conversions/esp_jpg_decode.c:19:
C:/Users/Patron/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_rom/include/esp32/rom/tjpgd.h:91:28: note: expected 
'UINT (*)(JDEC *, BYTE *, UINT)' {aka 'unsigned int (*)(JDEC *, unsigned char *, unsigned int)'} but argument is of type 
'uint32_t (*)(JDEC *, uint8_t *, uint32_t)' {aka 'long unsigned int (*)(JDEC *, unsigned char *, long unsigned int)'}    
   91 | JRESULT jd_prepare (JDEC*, UINT(*)(JDEC*,BYTE*,UINT), void*, UINT, void*);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.pio/libdeps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/conversions/esp_jpg_decode.c:117:32: warning: passing argument 2 of 'jd_decomp' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  117 |     jres = jd_decomp(&decoder, _jpg_write, (uint8_t)jpeg.scale);
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                |
      |                                uint32_t (*)(JDEC *, void *, JRECT *) {aka long unsigned int (*)(JDEC *, void *, JRECT *)}
In file included from .pio/libdeps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/conversions/esp_jpg_decode.c:19:
C:/Users/Patron/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/components/esp_rom/include/esp32/rom/tjpgd.h:92:27: note: expected 
'UINT (*)(JDEC *, void *, JRECT *)' {aka 'unsigned int (*)(JDEC *, void *, JRECT *)'} but argument is of type 'uint32_t (*)(JDEC *, void *, JRECT *)' {aka 'long unsigned int (*)(JDEC *, void *, JRECT *)'}
   92 | JRESULT jd_decomp (JDEC*, UINT(*)(JDEC*,void*,JRECT*), BYTE);
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1.exe: warning: command-line option '-fno-rtti' is valid for C++/D/ObjC++ but not for C
Compiling .pio\build\esp32cam\lib533\esp32-camera\conversions\to_jpg.o
Linking .pio\build\esp32cam\bootloader.elf
.pio/libdeps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/conversions/to_bmp.c:26:10: fatal error: esp32/spiram.h: No such file or directory
   26 | #include "esp32/spiram.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
*** [.pio\build\esp32cam\lib533\esp32-camera\conversions\to_bmp.o] Error 1
.pio/libdeps/esp32cam/esp32-camera/conversions/to_jpg.cpp:27:10: fatal error: esp32/spiram.h: No such file or directory
   27 | #include "esp32/spiram.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
*** [.pio\build\esp32cam\lib533\esp32-camera\conversions\to_jpg.o] Error 1
============================================= [FAILED] Took 633.54 seconds =============================================
```

EDIT: Found declaration of funtions seems to be declared as uint but ask for uint32

```
JRESULT jd_decomp (
    JDEC* jd,                               /* Initialized decompression object */
    UINT (*outfunc)(JDEC*, void*, JRECT*),  /* RGB output function */
    BYTE scale                              /* Output de-scaling factor (0 to 3) */
)
```

EDIT 2: now its working, had to install the correct version via boards from platformio, im adding my working platformio.ini file now, the error seems to be the older version (5.3) ask for uint but the new one (6.0) need a uint32 value, and since theres no oficial update from the esp32cam github i have to roll back

```
[env:esp32cam]
;src_file = main
platform = espressif32@5.3.0      ; <-- set this one to your working version
board = esp32cam
framework =  espidf ;esp-idf-v4.4.2
monitor_speed = 115200
;upload_port = COM[4]
lib_deps = espressif/esp32-camera@^2.0.0
;lib_deps = esp32-camera
build_flags = -I../lib/esp32-camera
; set freq cpu to 240 mhz
board_build.f_cpu = 240000000L
```

Comment: `espressif` went from 5.x.y to 6.0.1. This is a major version change. So, they are at liberty to make some internal/incompatible changes. Is there a newer version of `espcam32` that _is_ compatible with the newer `espressif`? It would help to see the [missing] prototypes [and/or definitions] for `jd_prepare` and `_jpg_write` to see what changed and why they're incompatible. For example, maybe `_jpg_write` got an extra arg [or different one] and `jd_prepare` didn't update for this.

Comment: @CraigEstey i did download the latest esp32cam from github yesterday just as a precaution still nothing, i did check jd_decomp declaration and got this, plz check edit on main post.
it seems it was declared as uint but the new one ask for unint32, not sure how to handle this

Comment: Theres any way to rollback to my previous version of espressif framework without uninstalling everythin? i dont want to mess everything up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to build with the specific version of the Espressif32 platform that works with the code.

You can pin a specific version by adding `@x.y.z` to the end of the platform name. For instance,

```
[esp32]
platform = espressif32@5.3.0
```

The espressif32 platform definitions are [checked into Github](https://github.com/platformio/platform-espressif32). You can get a list of releases by looking at the [repository's release history](https://github.com/platformio/platform-espressif32/releases). 5.3.0 is the last release before 6.0.0. Since you're not sure what release you'd previously used, I would start there and work backwards until you find one that works.

Note you can also pin frameworks to a specific version number as well, using the same syntax, as well as specific versions of libraries.

Comment: ok this did the magic trick, just an small note, i did installed the 5.3.0 version just goint into, PIO home -> boards -> search for the espressif 32 framework tag -> left side under installation selected my version -> hit install, finally just added the platform like you sugested above, thanks a lot

Comment: Glad you got it fixed!

Answer (score 1):

*Caveat:* Some guesses and suggestions ...

This answer is somewhat jumbled and train-of-thought. So, it might help for you to reread it a few times ...

---

I cloned `esp32-camera` from the github repo: https://github.com/espressif/esp32-camera.git

It appears that (e.g.) `_jpg_read` and `_jd_prepare` are *both* part of esp32-camera. So, AFAICT, they aren't part of the core `espressif` as far as esp32-camera is concerned. More on this below.

In the version I downloaded, in `target/esp32s2/private_include/tjpgd.h`, we have: `typedef unsigned int UINT;`

My guess is that this version of `tjpgd.h` has been copied into the esp32-camera repo from some version of the general `espressif`.

`_jsp_read` is in `conversions/esp_jpg_decode.c`:

```
static unsigned int _jpg_read(JDEC *decoder, uint8_t *buf, unsigned int len)
```

And, `jd_prepare` is in `target/esp32s2/private_include/tjpgd.h`:

```
JRESULT jd_prepare (JDEC*, UINT(*)(JDEC*,BYTE*,UINT), void*, UINT, void*);
```

Note that because of the typedef for `UINT`, the parameter in `jd_prepare` and the definition of `_jpg_read` *are* compatible.

---

In your later version of `espressif`, instead of `UINT`, the corresponding definition of `_jpg_read` uses `uint32_t`. This is a [more modern] standard, usually defined in `stdint.h`

I went looking for the core `esp32` source repo. There is one specifically for arduino, but I cloned: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf.git

It also uses `UINT`.

---

I cloned the `platformio` repo: https://github.com/platformio/platform-espressif32.git

It has `esp32cam.json` but this seems to be the arduino version.

---

I cloned the `arduino-esp32` repo: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32.git

---

I wasn't able to do much in the way of building as I'm not too familiar with `cmake`.

Again, all of this is just a lot guesswork on my part ...

But, AFAICT, the camera repo has private copies of the main repo files (e.g. `tjpgd.h`).

Your build is complaining about a *missing* `esp32/spiram.h`. I found this *only* in the `arduino-esp32` repo!!!

So, it may depend upon *where* you're downloading your various components. If they're downloaded from the same repo, they should work better.

For example, are you getting all sources from github's `espressif`? Can you build with *just* repos cloned from `espressif` and [perhaps, temporarily] forego `platformio`?

In other words, *I* am not sure how `platformio` factors into this. A guess, from what I mentioned above, is that `platformio` has a config for the *arduino* version of the camera.

So, maybe `platformio` and `espressif` repos don't mix ...

Or, you need to tell `platformio` to use the `espidf` *framework* (in `esp32cam.json`) instead of the `arduino` framework

Comment: actually i did partially the same as you, sort of, i did indeed cloned the esp32cam repo from github and add it as a submodule using git, but had to copy it to components folder instead of lib, i did had to also add **build_flags = -I../lib/esp32-camera** to the platformio.ini file, but dont know why but it works that way, im using platformio installed via plugins from inside vscode, i didnt wanted to mess around with the github version, but i would check it in the future once they add support for the new S6, im editing my question with the final ini file that im using and working now, thanks